# Как обернуть каждые 3 поста в div с помощью query_posts?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Пытаюсь вывести по 3 поста в div. Это будет слайдер, в каждом слайде которого по 3 поста.
Но у меня остается незакрытый div, причем пустой. Что я сделал не так? Поправьте пожалуйста

```
<?php
    $vpargs1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', // тип поста
        'category_name' => 'announcment',   
        'posts_per_page' => '6',         
        'orderby' => 'publish_date', // поле для сортировки
        'order' => 'DESC', // метод сортировки
        'post_status' => 'publish', // опубликованные
        'offset' => 0 // сколько пропустить записей
    );
    $vps_loop1 = new WP_Query($vpargs1);
    ?>     
    <div class="carousel-item row announce-row active">   
    <?php 
    $i = 1;
    if($vps_loop1->have_posts()): while($vps_loop1->have_posts()):
        $vps_loop1->the_post();
        $itemid = get_the_ID();
        $pole1 = get_post_meta($itemid, 'pole1', true);
        ?>            
            <div class="announce-item col-md-4">
                <div class="announce-item__inner">
                    <b class="announce-date"><?php the_field('date_start'); ?> - <?php the_field('date_end'); ?></b>
                    <a class="announce-title" href="<?php echo !empty($pole1) ? $pole1 : get_permalink($itemid); ?>">
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>            
       <?php 
        if ($i % 3 == 0){ ?>
            </div><div class="carousel-item row announce-row">
            <?php } ?>
            <?php $i++; ?>                 
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При 6-ой итерации у тебя опять открывается `<div class="carousel-item row announce-row">`, но он уже не закрывается.

Что-бы не путаться, можно массив постов разбить на 2 массива по 3 поста